# Mapping over a data set to get values to use in another map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a React app that displays farmer's markets in Philadelphia as markers on a Google Map using the react-google-maps library.

After creating a Google map, I am accessing the farmer's market data through an ArcGIS API, and looping over the data array to return a marker for each farmer's market.

I'm running into an issue because the data I have for the locations in ArcGIS is returning the information as x y coordinates when I need them to be in latitude and longitude for Google Maps to be able to display them. Luckily, ArcGIS has a [module](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-support-webMercatorUtils.html#xyToLngLat) to make that conversion and a way to [use these modules in React](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/react/).

Where I'm stuck is how to successfully render the marker, which means mapping over the dataset to first convert the coordinates and then use the converted coordinates in each instance of a marker. With the below code, I get "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." I'm a little lost with this, any help would be much appreciated!

```
const Map = () => {
  const [markets, setMarkets] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(res => {
        setMarkets(res.data.features)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[])

  return (
    <GoogleMap 
      defaultZoom={12}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 39.952583, lng: -75.165222 }}
    >
      {loadModules(['esri/geometry/support/webMercatorUtils'])
        .then(([webMercatorUtils]) => {
          markets.map(market => {
          let latLong = webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(market.geometry.x, market.geometry.y)
          return <Marker 
            key={market.attributes.OBJECTID} 
            position={{
              lat: latLong[1],
              lng: latLong[0]
            }}/>  
          })
        })}
    </GoogleMap>
  )}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map))
export default WrappedMap
```

Comment: `loadModules` is a promise, so you can't render it directly. You need to do your asynchronous stuff when component mounts, store the _results_ in the state (both `webMercatorUtils` and `markets` by the looks), then render the `<Marker />` components from those state values. You can' just render a promise directly. So Basically, do for `webMercatorUtils` what you did for `markets` with a hook, and then when both those async values have been fetched, render the `<Marker />`s

Comment: Thanks! I put the promise inside a useEffect:
`  const [latLong, setLatLong] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    loadModules(['esri/geometry/support/webMercatorUtils'])
    .then(([webMercatorUtils]) => {
      markets.map(market => {
        let convertedCoords = webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(market.geometry.x, market.geometry.y)
        return setLatLong(convertedCoords)
      })  
    })
  }, [])` 
but `latLong` returns an empty array. If I console.log the result of loadModules outside useEffect w/o set state, I get arrays with the correct coordinates, but no way to access them